# How to select the records from one table which is not matching with the other two tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, msbi

I have one master table emp1 table with 3 columns and 3 rows as you can see below

```
empid empname empsal
1     a       100
2     b       300
3     c       500
```

second table emp2 with 3 columns and 1 row

```
empid empname empsal
1     a       100
```

suppose, if I have to pick the records which are only available in the first table but not in second table then I can use the below query

```
select * FROM emp1 b 
  LEFT JOIN emp2 f ON f.empid = b.empid 
      WHERE f.id IS NULL
```

but here I have third table emp3 with 3 columns and 1 row

```
empid empname empsal
2     b       300
```

if I have to pick the records which are available in the first table only, but not in second and third table, what could be the best solution?

Comment: Hint: `NOT EXISTS`

Comment: Can I have the query please

Comment: Add another left join to emp3 and add a condition to the where clause " AND emp3.id is NULL"

Comment: @RafaelNadal Yes you can have it, which also you can mark it as accepted if it works and solve your issue.

Comment: similar questions asked a gazillion times.

Comment: actually I am new here, sorry for that, however, in the above question I have mention it in a simple way, but the thing is second and third table don't have the same number of columns as first table has

Comment: @RafaelNadal It's ok, but please read **[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)** and take the **[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)** :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many ways to do it, here is one using `NOT IN`:

```
CREATE TABLE Emp1 (
    empid INT, 
    empname VARCHAR(25),
    empsal INT
    );

CREATE TABLE Emp2 (
    empid INT, 
    empname VARCHAR(25),
    empsal INT
    );

CREATE TABLE Emp3 (
    empid INT, 
    empname VARCHAR(25),
    empsal INT
    );

INSERT INTO Emp1 VALUES
(1,     'a',       100),
(2,     'b',       300),
(3,     'c',       500);

INSERT INTO Emp2 VALUES
(1,     'a',       100);

INSERT INTO Emp3 VALUES
(2,     'b',       300);

SELECT *
FROM Emp1
WHERE empid NOT IN ( SELECT empid FROM Emp2 UNION SELECT empid FROM Emp3);
```

Results:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| empid | empname | empsal |
+-------+---------+--------+
|     3 | c       |    500 |
+-------+---------+--------+
```

**[Demo](http://rextester.com/EIJ42535)**

Comment: @RafaelNadal Glad to help :)

Comment: Actually, I have more than 30 millions records in the first table and I need to check with other 25 tables with that first table, in this case, what could be the best solution based on performance, thanks!

Comment: @RafaelNadal I think I see that ^ question before, and you get solutions for it, and that what was Mitch Wheat refering to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47372361/how-to-select-the-records-from-one-table-which-is-not-matching-with-the-other-tw/47372466?noredirect=1#comment81697631_47372361)

Comment: Suppose, if I don't have same number of columns in the other two tables (emp2 has only 4 columns and emp3 has 5 columns) then what could be the solution?? anyone please help!!

Comment: @RafaelNadal Did I use the other columns in my answer? No, you don't need them even Emp2 table has 5 columns and Emp3 has 10 columns, the important thing is the ID. Try to play with the demo included.